# Why Beautifull arrangment not working in c

Tags: java, c

```
void check(int start, int* count, int size, int * set)
{
    if(start == size) {
        (*count) += 1;
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i = start; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if((set[start] == 0) && (((i+1) % (start +1) == 0) || (start + 1) % (i+1) == 0 ))
        {
            set[start] = 1;
            check(start +1, count, size, set);
            set[start] = 0;
        }
    }
}


int countArrangement(int n){
    int* set = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    memset(set, 0, sizeof(int) * n);
    int count = 0;
    check(0, &count, n, set);
    return count;
}
```

this is the code translated from java to c but the problem is , when n is greater than 6 then the result is wrong
for 7 it increase by one but after that the result is always smaller than the expected value, I am not able to understand what am i missing at.

Your answer
1
2
3
8
10
36
42
128
216
600
660
3456
3744
9408
18900

Expected answer
1
2
3
8
10
36
41
132
250
700
750
4010
4237
10680
24679

that java code

```
public class Solution {
    int count = 0;
    public int countArrangement(int N) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[N + 1];
        calculate(N, 1, visited);
        return count;
    }
    public void calculate(int N, int pos, boolean[] visited) {
        if (pos > N)
            count++;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            if (!visited[i] && (pos % i == 0 || i % pos == 0)) {
                visited[i] = true;
                calculate(N, pos + 1, visited);
                visited[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you just point out the missing part?

Comment: so, this is actually a c question?

Comment: Just run it through a debugger and watch all variables.

Comment: @Stultuske kind a middle of that, the issue is that it is working in java but the translation is not working in c

Comment: @hsuecu meaning that your issue is with the c code, hence, a c question.

Comment: In Java, as well as in C, array indexing begins at `[0]`. The Java adds 1 to the array allocation but your C code does not.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is there in the post itself as your answer and expected answer. in terms of input the input n is 1<=n<=15

Comment: @WeatherVane i took  care of that, and that extra cell is to avoid the encounter with zero

Comment: Well, it does not look like a "translation" but "based on". It doesn't help that you have used differntly named identifiers.

Comment: Unrelated: `foo = malloc(...); memset(foo, 0, ...);` may be written as `foo = calloc(...);`

Comment: @WeatherVane whatever you think of it, but the fact is it is working in java but not in c . And why is this happening

Comment: @pmg but that shouldn't mess up with the output.

Comment: The recursion termination check is different (even allowing for changing from 1-based to 0-based). The Java checks `if (pos > N)` but the C checks for equality with `if(start == size)` I suggest you step/trace and find out how the computation differs. You know which incarnation it is.

Comment: Related? [OEIS A320843](https://oeis.org/A320843)?

Comment: @WeatherVane but why is only started to put its effect after n is greater than 7 . And the pos is non index value and start is a index value, the check is based on start+1 which turn it into the non index value. shouldn't it cancel the difference

Comment: The parenthesiztion of `if((set[start] == 0) && ((i+1) % (start +1) == 0) || (start + 1) % (i+1) == 0 )` is different. Please take a close look. In the Java version the two ORred terms are parenthesised.

Comment: @pmg well you found the recurrsive path which fails the time test, this is backtracking using a set array.

Comment: @WeatherVane the comment is not valid

Comment: I'm not a java expert but the C implementation seems very different.... as-if you are trying a different algo. Why? Wouldn't it be better to follow the same?

Comment: The need is not for the argument but the need is of the missing link identification, if someone says about the logical statement then you should consider reading the post as the output till n = 6 is correct , but why is it getting wrong after n= 7 .

Comment: Do you mean *my* statement is false?  The Java code has `(pos % i == 0 || i % pos == 0)`. The two terms are parenthesized so the OR is performed before the AND. The C code has `((i+1) % (start +1) == 0) || (start + 1) % (i+1) == 0`. The two terms are not parenthesized but in C `&&` had a higher precendence than `||`. That is not the same as the Java code which explicitly forces the precedence.

Comment: @WeatherVane then why the difference only comes after n = 7 , why is that.

Comment: That isn't relevant, but the translation error is.

Comment: @hsuecu `a && b || c` is not the same as `a && (b || c)` so Weather Vane has a very good point...

Comment: ok ok . but why the difference only shows up after n = 7

Comment: if((set[start] == 0)&&(((start+1) % (i+1) == 0) || ((i+1) % (start+1) == 0)))

Comment: Sorry, but that is like asking "why does my undefined behaviour sometimes work?

Comment: but the error is still there

Comment: You have two options: a) deploy the debugger, b) make a one-to-one transalation, instead of also making the functional change of the array indexing.

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you mean sir

Comment: @hsuecu Again... why is your C algo different from the java algo.

Comment: @4386427like  how much

Comment: Like... completely... The java code index the array using `i`. The C code index the array using `start`

Comment: The C code has a `return` statement. The java code doesn't.

Comment: You are **not** doing a one-to-one conversion of the basic algo

Comment: IMO it was clearly a misjudgement to convert to 0-based array, because you have to add the 1 back again to perform the computations.

Comment: OT: Your C code leaks memory. There is no call of `free`

Comment: BTW: Does `main` simply do: `for (int i = 1; i < SomeLimit; ++i) printf("%d ", countArrangement(i));` ?

Comment: And also... Your C code uses different names for the same things... why?

Answer (score 1):

> this is the code translated from java to c

Well, not really.

You have **not** made a one-to-one translation. The C code is (perhaps by mistake) using a completely different algorithm.

Start by making a one-to-one translation. Once you have that working, you can start playing with algorithm changes. But don't do both in the same step.

A one-to-one translation would be more like:

```
void calculate(int N, int pos, int * visited, int* count)
{
    if (pos > N)
        (*count)++;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (!visited[i] && (pos % i == 0 || i % pos == 0)) {
            visited[i] = 1;
            calculate(N, pos + 1, visited, count);
            visited[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int countArrangement(int n)
{
    int* set = calloc(n+1, sizeof *set);
    int count = 0;
    calculate(n, 1, set, &count);
    free(set);
    return count;
}
```

Notice how the C code for `calculate` is almost identical to the java version. No change of algorithm - only a few changes required due to language differences.